# How can I add auto weight to a new object and use the animation from other object?

Tags: animation

I had a 3d model animated. Now I want to add one more object upon the old model. How can I add auto weight to my new object so that it follows the animation sequence?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this model is rigged, so parent the new object to the model, with empty groups. go to the vertex groups, and select the bone you want it to be parented to. go into edit mode, select the vertices you want animated, and assign them to the correct bone.

Comment: Is there any way to Quick delete weight from armature? So i auto weight again?

Comment: yes, select the mesh, and go to the vertex tab, look for the vertex groups, and when you click the arrow on the right of those vertex groups, you'll get a menu with the option to remove them

Comment: No problem, please mark as solved if this answer solved your question.